# Schema::dropIfExists() Deleted ALL tables in DB on migrate:rollback

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, migration

I ran `php artisan migrate:rollback` on command line, so the migration deleted ALL TABLES in db.

There is only one migration created but have others tables in used db.

The laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#renaming-and-dropping-tables) says:

> To drop an existing table, you may use the `drop` or `dropIfExists` methods.

and the function `down()` on migration code is the default like as bellow:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer('image')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name', 64);
            $table->string('slug', 64)->unique();
            $table->integer('price')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

I don't think the `Schema::dropIfExists('products')` work properlly in this case, this is a bug? or my(and laravel documentation) mistake?

Comment: What other tables? If you have other tables in your DB, you *should* also have migrations for them, and in those migrations, there should be a `down()` function that calls `Schema::drop()` (or `dropIfExists()`). Probably going to need a bit more information on this. I can't say I've heard of something like that happening.

Comment: Is a existing database of older versions. i don't even created the others migrations yet because there are more than 100 table in db

Answer (score 1):

Roll back, rolls back each migration of the last batch.

If your all migration in **same batch** then it will rollback all the migrations. So your all tables will be deleted from the database.

[image]

Comment: But in my project there was no others migrations

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is over a year old, but this might help others who are having this issue and are looking for a solution. I'm guessing what happened here is if you run `php artisan migrate:rollback` it will rollback all migrations from the last batch. In other words, it wil run all `down()` functions in all the migrations in the same batch. So if you have made a `down()` function in those migrations where you revert the changes (deleting the created table), those will be ran as well.

To prevent this, you can add the `--step` parameter to indicate how many migrations should be rolled back, like so: `php artisan migrate:rollback --step=1`. Then only your last migration will be rolled back.